# Finding the Maclaurin polynomial of order 6 of: $f(x)=x\ln(1+x^{3})\ln(1-x^{2})$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Find the Maclaurin polynomial of order 6 of:
$$f(x)=x\ln(1+x^{3})\ln(1-x^{2})$$

The result I get doesn't make sense.

my try:

because:  $\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$

$$\ln(1+x^{3})=x^{3}-\frac{x^{6}}{2}+\frac{x^{9}}{3}+x^{9}\varepsilon_{1}(x^{3}) = x^{3}+x^{5}\varepsilon_{2}(x)$$

$$\ln(1-x^{2})=-x^{2}-\frac{x^{4}}{2}-\frac{x^{6}}{6}-x^{6}\varepsilon_{1}(-x^{2}) = -x^{2}-\frac{x^{4}}{2}+x^{5}\varepsilon_{3}(x)$$

$f(x)=x\ln(1+x^{3})(1-x^{2})=x(x^{3}+x^{5}\varepsilon_{2}(x))(-x^{2}-\frac{x^{4}}{2}+x^{5}\varepsilon_{3}(x))$

$=(x^{4}+x^{6}\varepsilon_{2}(x))(-x^{2}-\frac{x^{4}}{2}+x^{5}\varepsilon_{3}(x))=-x^{6}+x^{6}\varepsilon_{4}(x)\Longrightarrow P_{6,0}(x)=-x^{6}$

But this doesn't make sense at all, I guess I wrote nonsense :(

Would appreciate any help :)

Comment: sry it should be ln

Comment: I am a bit confused what part "doesn't make sense at all" except for writing the error terms in a strange way.

Comment: After your edit: your answer is right, why did you think it's wrong?

Comment: @AndréArmatowski can you show me how to write it xD?

Comment: @runway44 I don't know, it seems wrong to me

Comment: If we consider $e^{x}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k}}{k!}$ I would write $1+x+x^{2}/2+O(x^3)$ where $O(x^{3})$ is [Big O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) or $1+x+x^{2}/2+R_2(x)$ where $R_{2}(x)$ is the [Lagrange remainder](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeRemainder.html). In either case I would use "$+\text{Remainder}$" rather than "$\times\text{Remainder}$".

Comment: @AndréArmatowski thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after writing out the first terms of the maclaurin expansion of $\ln(1+x^3)$ and $\ln(1-x^2)$ , observe that the only way to get an $x^6$ term is to multiply $x$ and the 2 first terms $x^3$ and $-x^2$. thus the order 6 maclaurin polynomial has only one term $-x^6$.

the maclaurin expansion does not have an $x^7$ term as there are no positive integer solutions $(a,b)$ for the eqn $1+2a+3b=7$.